# Tracking down excessive retain/release in Swift

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting

I'm porting a path tracer in Swift (for fun). It's using a simple octree acceleration structure, implemented as a `SpatialIndex` class with a `[SpatialIndex?]` property for the child nodes. I wrote a method for testing the acceleration structure by just finding the nearest point to some arbitrary point. The first method was recursive, and that worked well. I then tried implementing a loop-based approach which also works fine, but it's 3x slower and much of that time is spent on retain/release calls.

The thing is, I don't really understand why it needs more retain/release calls than the recursive approach and I don't know how to track down what's actually being ARC'd. In this case, reference counting makes up around half the time spent. That seems a bit excessive, to say the least.

When I search for ARC issues, I mostly find things related to retention loops and that sort of thing. What I'd really like to be able to do is effectively bypass the entire system since I know the memory layout of the tree cannot change.

So my question is basically: when ARC is causing performance issues, what are the best options for tracking down what it's actually spending time reference counting, and how do I speed it up?

Comment: Have you profiled your app with Instruments?

Comment: @MartinR sure, but all it told me was that the retain/release calls are happening, not *why* they are happening

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Unmanaged` type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unmanaged) to bypass ARC for particular objects. I haven't tried this much, but I imagine it would look something like this:

1. Before the performance-critical section, wrap the objects for which you want to skip ARC in `Unmanaged` values:

   ```
   let unmanagedObj = Unmanaged.passRetained(obj)
   ```
2. Inside the critical section, passing the `Unmanaged` value around will not entail reference counting overhead. When you need to use the object, extract it like this:

   ```
   let obj = unmanagedObj.takeUnretainedValue()
   ```
3. After the critical section, release the object:

   ```
   unmanagedObj.release()
   ```

Of course, this only works as long as you control the functions you need to pass the object to because you have to change them from taking an object to taking an `Unmanaged` value. I don't know if that's the case for you.

Maybe you can figure out which types of objects cause the most reference counting overhead in your code by switching different parts of the object graph to `Unmanaged`.